# Можно ли русифицировать Spyder в Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Можно ли русифицировать Spyder в Anaconda. если да то как или где находится русификатор?

Comment: а зачем? меню на английском слишком сложное?

Comment: мне не сложно понять суть вопроса, даже не смотря на то, что вы дважды ошиблись в написании названия программы. мне сложно понять, зачем вам руссифицировать spyder.

Comment: На РУССКОЯЗЫЧНОМ Stackoverflow при  наличии отличной, огромной, многолюдной, суперинформативной  английской версии вопрос "а зачем руссифицировать " звучит немного странно.

Comment: @passant какой интересный комментарий. по форме он вроде бы порицает мой вопрос, а по духу - полностью меня поддерживает.

Comment: @strawdog -  уж точно, я никого "порицать" не хотел. А что-до локализации интерфейса. Я говорю (почти свободно) на четырех языках, читаю -  еще на двух. И в начале 90-ых тоже гордо думал "зачем руссифицировать интерфейс Windows, английский для программиста должен быть вторым родным". А оказалось, что комфортнее все-таки, когда интерфейс на родном языке. А документацию, статьи да и любую другую техническую информацию всегда стоит читать именно на языке оригинала. Это факт. Хотя наличие русскоязычного Stackoverflow говорит, что 90% аудитории с английским мягко говоря не дружат. А стОит.

Comment: @passant руссификация ОС с тонной техподдержки и целой командой локализации, и руссификация специализированного ide - две большие разницы. Главное, чтобы как на "локализованном" Алиэкспресс не получилось.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На данный момент Spyder [переведен на русский язык только на 57%](https://crowdin.com/project/spyder),
из-за этого он [добавлен в список "отключенных" языков](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/blob/d6bcb86edccd1aaf2f32f01b8f8806841e11d8c4/spyder/config/base.py#L363):

```
# Disabled languages because their translations are outdated or incomplete
DISABLED_LANGUAGES = ['hu', 'ru', 'pl']
```

Вы можете вручную убрать его из этого списка в файле `spyder/config/base.py` - тогда русский язык появится в списке в настройках (сам файл перевода в spyder есть, нужно только убрать русский язык из отключенных). Также вы можете [доработать перевод на crowdin](https://crowdin.com/project/spyder), тогда его могут активировать для всех пользователей.

**UPD.** На данный момент перевод добит до 81%, и русский язык [убран из DISABLED_LANGUAGES](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/commit/47c8e555a12a21b76a3377a95ce2185fa10e641f). Начиная с версии Spyder 5.0.4 русский язык можно выбрать в настройках IDE:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: @Vopos, если ответ вам помог, вы можете отметить его принятым - поставить галку слева от ответа.

Comment: @insolor  Уважаемый insolor. Вы бы не могли подсказать, в какой именно директорий (в Windows) устанавливается поддиректорий spyder/config/?

Comment: @passant нужно смотреть куда ведет ярлык Spyder и искать там. В зависимости от способа установки (если устанавливать из anaconda или отдельно) скорее всего будет в разных местах.

Answer (score 2):

Руссифицировать интерфейс можно и легко.
Tools->Preferences->Advanced Setting->Русский->Apply -> перезагрузка Spyder.

Comment: я скачал последнюю версию. в выпадающем списке языков нет русского языка. я только начал изучать Python. Английский я знаю. но в начале лучше все таки учиться на русской версии программы. так легче. русификатор я не нашел. так же языковые пакеты в инете не нашел. смотрел и на зарубежных сайтах. хотя в некоторых видеоуроках видел русскую версию программы. но в любом случае спасибо за ответ passant. кратко и четко по делу.

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за рекомендации. Сначала убрала русский из заблокированных языков по свету insolor'а. Затем в самой программе по пути, указанному passant'ом смогла поменять язык на русский - он появился в списке